# How to set default ConstraintMode in JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I don't want to have any foreign keys when I generate the DDL for my database.

According to `javax.persistence.ConstraintMode` there is a default value:

```
/**
 * Use the provider-defined default behavior.
 */
PROVIDER_DEFAULT
```

So how do I set the default in Hibernate?

I'm using Hibernate through Spring Boot Data JPA.

Comment: I don't see a way to configure that globally. The documentation doesn't even mention this: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

Comment: Why would you not want foreign keys?

Comment: That's just how my actual database is set up.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this in https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/88acc9511b2e1c1cee7def27ba8dc717a8c321f8 , please check it out, thanks.